# Authorization with access_token bearer in websocket

Tags: javascript, next.js, websocket, jwt, access-token

I'm making a real-time chat api, in which I'm listening to messages sent with socket.io, and at the same time making a post-type request to my api to create the message within the database, however, I want add authorization with a generated access_token, which is passed through a function in the front-end of my code. The question is this, is it a bad idea to pass this access_token through the websocket event every time the front-end creates a message button for a triggered?

// returns logged in user information.

````
"use server";

import { SessionData } from "@/types/types";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

import { api } from "../lib/api";
import { signJwtAccessToken } from "../lib/jwt";

const getUser = async () => {
  const session = await getServerSession();

  try {
    const data: SessionData = session;
    const login = data.user.email;
    const currentUserResponse = await api.get(`/user/${login}`);
    const user = currentUserResponse.data.user;

    const accessToken = signJwtAccessToken(user);

    const result = {
      ...user,
      accessToken,
    };

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};

export default getUser;


// code triggered to send an event to webscoket
interface FriendProps {
  friendId: string;
}

const createMessage = async (
  friendId: FriendProps,
  content: FormDataEntryValue | null
) => {
  const user = await getUser();
  const friendsId = friendId;
  const userId = user.id;
  const receiver = await api.get(
    `receiverUserId/${userId}/friend/${friendsId}`
  );
  const receiverId = receiver.data.receiverId[0].id;

  try {
    socket.emit("send-msg", {
      content,
      friendsId,
      userId,
      receiverId,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export default createMessage; ```
````

Comment: I ended up changing some things, instead of passing all messages, sending the accessToken only when connecting to the socket. So I can use it as authorization in the request, but the question is still the same, is there a problem with that?

Comment: "*I'm listening to messages and at the same time making a post-type request to my api*" - that's weird. Why not use only one of these?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to fit to the description.

Comment: What does this question have to do with [[tag:n]]?

Comment: I'm listening to messages and at the same time making a post-type request to my API, because every time a message is heard via websocket, I make a request to the api, inserting the message into the database.

Comment: Wait, is the websocket not connected to your API already but to something else?